# Resource processing and process monitoring in RESTful Web Services

Tags: web-services, rest

Consider a RESTful Web Service processing large documents on the server side. It could be a document converter accepting multi-paged or single-paged digital images and converting them to PDF. The user has the possibility to compose the final PDF from several images by inserting them into the virtual document via REST. This means that API users will make several requests before the conversion can be started.

Now my question:
I need to signal the Web Service to start document processing. Because such a processing can take some time (considering a video converter, for example), some kind of monitoring is required, in order to be able to display progress information in the front-end.

How is this done in the modern RESTful Web Services? Or, in other words, is it possible to implement this nicely in the RESTful world (i.e. without resorting to some sort of RPC)?

I'd appreciate real examples and useful links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[202 Accepted](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3)

> The 202 (Accepted) status code indicates that the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
>
> The representation sent with this response ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed) a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when the request will be fulfilled.

In short, there is a "report on the progress of this instance of the process" resource, which the client can monitor.